# Is it possible convert WindowBuilder GUI editor code to NetBeans GUI editor code?

Tags: java, eclipse, user-interface, netbeans, windowbuilder

I've created a Java Swing Project and I design the GUI using Window Builder in Eclipse. Now, I've to switch to Netbeans for some reasons and I would like to continue with this project.

However, I saw that Netbeans GUI editor didn't recognize the classes that I've created with Window Builder and I don't find an easy way to do that.

Is it possible, in some way, to convert the WindowBuilder generated code to Netbeans GUI editor code?

Comment: `Is it possible, in some way, to convert the WindowBuilder generated code to Netbeans GUI editor code?` - and you are going to make the same mistake twice. If you are able to convert the code, then then next time you change IDE you will have the same problem. Don't use an IDE to generated your code. You should manually create your forms and code and use the IDE as a tool to help compile/debug etc.

Comment: @camickr With WindowBuilder that's not a problem, since WindowBuilder generates nothing but code and also can parse/render/edit arbitrary UI code that was written by hand. There is no "secret" or proprietary storage format of the UI like NetBeans relies on. It's like saying "don't let Eclipse generate your `toString()` or `hashCode()` because when you switch IDEs you won't be able to maintain them" - nonsense, it's just code that an developer can maintain, with or without Eclipse.

Comment: There's no "coversion," it's just that NetBeans doesn't have the ability to parse *any* UI code into it's own GUI building tool.